How to use an RC circuit and calculate values for a flip flop reset
I've found some examples of using an RC circuit to set the initial value of a flip flop. That includes this answer and this one. I've been searching for information on this and I'm still trying to put the last bits about how to use an RC circuit like this together. I want to use one to keep this flip flop output set to 0 on startup:

(The set and reset pins on this are active when high.)
If I understand what I've been reading, the RC circuit attached to pin 4, the Reset pin on the FF, should be able to hold the Reset line high for a time after power up, then let it go down. This should set the output at pin 1, Q, to 0 and it should stay at 0 until I press SW1, when it should toggle on. Pressing S1 again makes it toggle off. This would let me turn the relay on and off with just a momentary switch (as opposed to a SPST switch).  (And I'm aware I will probably add Schmitt Trigger gates between the RC circuit and pin 4 to reduce noise issues.)
I have noticed, on the 2nd example I linked to above, and in other schematics, a diode included. On different schematics, I've seen a diode across R1, but I've also seen it used in other places.
Here's what I'm not clear about:

Will this circuit hold Pin 4 high or low, as it is? (If it holds it low, I know I can use an inverter to solve that. I'm open to ideas that can handle inverting without an extra component. I also could just use Q bar for output instead of having to add an inverter between the RC circuit and Pin 4, couldn't I?)
Why do some versions of an RC circuit use a diode and what function does it do?
How do I calculate the values for the resistor and capacitor for this circuit? I'm not sure what formula to use.


"Schmitt Trigger gates between the RC circuit and pin 4 to reduce noise issues" On pin 4 it will provide a clean and fast logic level transition, despite the "slow" RC charge. A push button directly at the clock will cause problems as it will generate several edges. A debounce circuit is needed in this case.

Here are two RC circuits (with R and C swapped in the second one), where I apply +5V power suddenly, then I remove that power just as suddenly:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Blue is power input, orange is the potential at X, and brown is potential at Y:

From this it is clear that the left pair, R1 & C1 (orange) will not do what you want. When the input IN rises, X rises shortly after, eventually settling at +5V also. Connected to RESET (R pin) of your IC, this would hold \$Q=0\$ permanently.
What you require is a short duration pulse, which the right-hand circuit (brown) provides. Y jumps up suddenly when power is applied, but it decays back to zero after some time. That's a nice pulse behaviour, which would assert RESET only momentarily at power on. The caveat is that when power is removed, again Y jumps down, becoming negative. The diode you mentioned is to suppress that negative part:

simulate this circuit

It's not perfect, but the diode conducts heavily when Y becomes more negative than -0.7V. This effectively "clamps" the potential at Y to \$V_Y > -0.7V\$. Most ICs do not tolerate potentials far lower than their own negative supply (0V), at their inputs, and this diode mitigates that.
One reason you don't always see the diode present is that many ICs already contain diodes to perform this very function, protecting their inputs from electrostatic discharge (ESD). Another is that when power is removed, generally the supply rail doesn't instantly fall to 0V, so the negative pulse isn't as severe as I've shown here.
However, the built-in diodes are weak, and can be easily damaged by persistent current, and it's always good to give them a helping hand. I feel that in this scenario it's foolish to omit the diode for the sake of a few cents and a couple of mm2, without good reason.
You might consider using a schottkey diode (like the 1N5817), which has a forward voltage more like 0.3V, and which would be even more effective at suppressing the negative excursion.

If you assume that the switching threshold of the IC input lies somewhere near the mid-point of the supply potentials, say +2.5V, then you can see that using components with the values shown will yield a pulse duration equivalent to about 10ms.
The product \$\tau = R \times C\$ is called the time constant. \$\tau\$ is the time it takes for Y to go 63% of the way to its final value (which is very close to 50%, half way). In this case, \$\tau = 10k\Omega \times 1\mu F = 10ms\$. Therefore you choose R and C to have a product approximately equal to the duration of pulse you require.
Lower R means more current drawn from the supply, so I consider 10kΩ to be on the low end. The CMOS input connected to Y draws almost no current, so you could probably go into the hundreds of kilohms without problem, but I wouldn't recommend more than 100kΩ.

One more thing, connecting switch SW1 between clock (pin 3) and +3.3V will not work. When the switch is open, the clock pin is disconnected, and its potential is undefined. It becomes an antenna for noise picked up from sources nearby. You need a pull-up or pull-down resistor. You'll also find that the switch will "bounce". Instead of a clean switching action, what you'll get is a bunch of rapid connections and disconnections before settling into a persistent connected state. You will need to "debounce" this switch.

It was correctly pointed out in the comments that sometimes the power-on pulse from a simple RC arrangement returns to zero too slowly to be compatible with certain digital inputs. In this application I don't think it's a problem, but for future reference, I'll address that here.
A typical digital system could contain many flip-flops that could benefit from a power-on reset pulse, and it may be worthwhile to provide a better, cleaner one that all can use. The slow-slewing output from an RC high-pass filter can be cleaned up with a schmitt trigger, which uses positive feedback to implement hysteresis to overcome the ambiguity in logic level of a signal that's slowly passing through an already ambiguous switching threshold. Such a solution might use gates with schmitt-trigger inputs, such as those in a 74HC14, 40106 or 74'132:

simulate this circuit
Ignore the vertical scale, I've just shifted traces upwards to separate them:

The RST signal is a positive pulse that occurs at power-on, useful for active-high reset inputs such as your 4027. This is inverted by G2 to produce a reset pulse suitable for active-low inputs, if you needed it.

Wow! Great answer with SO much useful information - but it leaves me with many questions since I've got so much to learn. I hope you can answer a few in comments! In your diagram, Y uses a pull down resistor, right? Even with the cap there, it's a pull down? Debouncing: I know that's an issue, didn't want to include that in the scope here. I was thinking the mechanical action of the relay might be slow enough that bounce wasn't an issue, but I did more research and see that's not the case. So the relay might go back and forth, quickly, a few times. I have seen debouncing circuits I can use.

I also missed that I need the pull down resistor for the switch output and the other answer points out I need to ground pin 7. (So SW1 will work if I use a pull down?) Thank you for the info on the formula, so I could look it up and study it for things like learning what units and so on. Is the switch the only thing that needs debouncing? Is that an issue with relays? (And if I'm using a pull down for the switch, will adding a cap to it create an RC circuit that debounces the switch?)

Diode - I do remember that it seemed "backwards" in the circuits I looked at. Thanks for going into the detail on that! One other thought on the debouncing - the relay will bounce, too. So why not just debounce the relay, since that's the only thing the FF output feeds?

@Tango Welcome to EE.SE. You may access a Tour at the top right corner and learn more about how this site works. Specially the difference between a forum and a Q&A site should become more clear. You can open a new question, or more than one, add a reference to the excellent answer provided here, and receive further feedback even from Simon, to continue the learning process.

@Tango It's not appropriate to call my R2 a "pull-down" resistor. Together, R2 and C2 form an "RC high-pass filter", and that's what this arrangement should be called. A 10kΩ resistor between pin 3 and ground is fine, and this may be correctly referred to as a "pull-down resistor", since it holds pin 3 at 0V while SW1 is open. Also I overlooked floating pin 7, and it should indeed be connected to 0V. CMOS inputs should never be left unconnected, unless the datasheet tells you it's OK to do so.

@Tango When you say "debounce the relay", it's not clear what you mean. A relay has two distinct parts, the coil, and the switch contacts. The coil doesn't bounce, the switch contacts do, so it's the switch contacts of the relay that require debouncing.

Thank you for the clarification on the terminology for R2. I wanted a better understanding. (I also think, when I ask questions, about what is helping me and will help people in the future who search for the same answers!) Debouncing: I was looking at debouncing SW1 and then thought, "I'll have to debounce the relay switch, too, or debouncing the switch will do no good." But then it hit me that if I debounce the relay switch, then I really don't need to debounce SW1 as well, since all it connects to is the relay. So I thought, "Just debounce the relay."

@devnull I'm not trying to socialize. I'm asking questions for clarification. When I joined SE (on the SF board, over 13 years ago), I learned SE is to generate authoritative answers. For a person learning electronics, the questions, in the future, they're going to find the clarifications I'm asking for as helpful as I will find them now. While it could be debated about whether the follow-ups I'm asking should be separate questions, they're so closely related to this question, I'm sure there are many who find this who will be glad to see that information here.

While this answer is technically correct on the points, the used flipflop like many other logic gates are not specified and thus not intended to be used with slow signals with say 10ms RC time constant. This chip requires sharper edges than 45 us to work properly at 5V, and even faster edges to work properly at higher voltages. The only option is to use Schmitt triggers, or simply another type of switch debouncing to begin with.

@Justme Right, I'll suggest a fix for this when I have a moment. In this case, though, I think that the reset input is not going to have problems with a slow slewing signal. It might get a bit confused a few times during the transition, but I doubt it would ever do anything but reset, and it will be firmly low long before any activity occurs on its other pins. Still, better safe than sorry I suppose.


Will this circuit hold Pin 4 high or low, as it is? (If it holds it low, I know I can use an inverter to solve that. I'm open to ideas that can handle inverting without an extra component. I also could just use Q bar for output instead of having to add an inverter between the RC circuit and Pin 4, couldn't I?)

No. The circuit as drawn will hold pin low at startup (assuming the circuit has been de-energized for a long time. More on that later).
Your invertor idea will work, but a better way is to simply swap the locations of C1 and R1 to invert the function - no additional logic required.
Using Q' won't work - the circuit will still startup in an indeterminant state (as shown).

Why do some versions of an RC circuit use a diode and what function does it do?

The diode I'm assuming you are referring to is to rapidly discharge the capacitor to get it back to it's initial discharged state. This is important if the circuit is un-powered and re-powered immediately - without the diode, the staedy-state chaged state of the capacitor is retained, and you will be back to the indeterminate start up state all over again.

How do I calculate the values for the resistor and capacitor for this circuit? I'm not sure what formula to use.

That will be tricky to do analytically since the asynchronous inputs don't have defined logic levels when used like this. Fortunately, this part of the circuit only has to be "good enough" in practice. Philosophically, you want the RC time constant to be long enough so that it serves it's purpose, but short enough that it discharges adequately between power cycles. But not too long that the asynchronous input takes forever to transition to a real logic level (may cause weird chip behavior/oscillating output).
Without doing the math or reviewing the datasheet, 1k and 0.1uF should get things working. If not, increase R1 to 4.7k, maybe even 10k. It's really not so critical. In production, you would find what works best, then, double the resistor or capacitor value to make sure it will work over all operating conditions, temperatures, and tolerances. (In real production, you would use a micro for this application).
Additional comments:
Pin 7 must be tied to ground - you can't leave it floating. Weird stuff could happen. Additionally, all the inputs (even the ones on the unused flip-flop) have to be tied to ground.
The chip needs to be bypassed with a capacitor across the chip VCC and VDD, especially on a breadboard. Again, weird stuff could happen.
Not sure of the specs of K1, but unless its coil is rated for like 10mA, you're going to need a transistor to drive it - you will almost certainly kill the flip-flop from over current. If that doesn't kill your chip, the back emf might do it. Either way, put a NPN transistor between the relay and IC.
One last problem you're going to have, and this might be the biggest, is contact bounce from the switch. What you will observe, is that sometimes you press the switch, and the circuit will "work". Other times, you might have to press it several times to get the relay to switch states.
I'm not going to elaborate on my last bit as it goes beyond the scope of your question - read about "contact bounce and logic circuits". There are ways to treat this (even with out the micro). But if you want more detail or a solution, open another question. Long story short, the flip-flop will toggle several times prior to settling on the final state due to the inherent kinematics of the mechanical switching contacts.

Some details.
First, you need to modify the push switch circuit. Add a pull-down resistor and a capacitance (say, 10k and 1uF.) Then, when you push the switch you will get a rising clock pulse. Time constant is 1.1RC, or 1uF x 10k = 11ms, slow enough to filter out switch bounce.
Next, make the reset pulse. Again, we can use RC time constant of about 11ms, but this isn't so fussy: 10k and 0.1uf for 1.1ms would be fine too. At power-on the cap will bring RESET high, then charge up through the 10k, bringing the pin low. A diode from the pin to GND prevents bringing the pin lower than GND at power off, preventing IC damage.
But wait, there’s more. The CD4027 can only source about 4mA. That's kind of light for a relay (at least, a reasonably priced one.) We can boost the relay drive with a transistor.  Also, we add a catch diode to suppress the flyback pulse when you turn the relay off.
Here's all that in operation (simulate it here):

Last thing: make sure you tie off the second CD4027 flop's inputs to GND. CMOS misbehaves when its inputs are left floating.

You've give a good answer - I already picked one, but I might change it. I'll see if I have enough points to offer a bounty so I can give one person the answer and the other the bounty. I brought up a thought on another answer: what about debouncing the signal off the relay switch? Since that will probably need debouncing anyway, maybe debounce that and don't worry about debouncing the switch. Also, thank you for the point about the current from the chip and the need for a transistor. I get the diode to handle discharge on the R pin circuit. Why the diode across the relay coil?

Also - thank you for providing numbers, but also providing the formula and the formula name (so I can look it up and study it). That's both an immediate help for this circuit AND it's a help for me to learn why you're saying what you are - so I don't just copy it and not learn anything.

When you switch off a current to an inductor suddenly, it generates a large reverse voltage ('flyback') that can damage the driver. The diode catches this flyback and dissipates it safely.

The switch debounce is necessary to avoid clocking the flop multiple times on the switch press. Otherwise you won't get the push-on / push-off behavior you expect.

So both the push button switch and the relay switch need debouncing?

I don’t know how you’re using the relay switch, so I can’t really answer that question.
